# How can i add Aliases to This discord bot command and how can i embed the bot's response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make an alias to the command slowmode, but I'm not sure how to do so. and I also want the bot to embed the response, instead of just sending it like a normal one. Help is appreciated!

```js
const command = message.content
        .slice(prefix.length)
        .toLowerCase()
        .split(" ")[0]
        .toLowerCase();

    const args = message.content
        .slice(prefix.length)
        .split(" ")
        .slice(1);

    if (command === "slowmode") {
        if(!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_CHANNELS")) return message.channel.send("You don't have access to this command!");

        // Checks if `args[0]` doesn't exist or isn't a number.
        if (!args[0]) return message.channel.send("You did not specify a correct amount of time!")
        if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("That is not a number!")

        // Check if `args[0]` is a correct amount of time to set slowmode
        // Array `validNumbers` are an array consistent of numbers of time you can set slowmode with.
        const validNumbers = [0, 5, 10, 15, 30, 60, 120, 300, 600, 900, 1800, 3600, 7200, 21600]

        // Check if `args[0]` parsed into an interger is included in `validNumbers`
        if(!validNumbers.includes(parseInt(args[0]))) return message.channel.send("Invalid Number! Number must be one of the following `5, 10, 15, 30, 60, 120, 300, 600, 900, 1800, 3600, 7200, 21600`.");

        // Set the slowmode
        message.channel.setRateLimitPerUser(args[0]);
        
        // Send the reply
        message.channel.send(`Slowmode Set to **${args[0]}**`)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just using an `if...else` chain for your command handler, making aliases is fairly easy with the [Logical `OR` Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators), which will return `true` if one of the multiple conditions are true.

```js
// if you have only one or two extra alias:
if (command === 'slowmode' || command = 'sm')
```

```js
const name = 'john'

if (name === 'james') console.log('Your name is james');
if (name === 'john') console.log('Your name is john');
if (name === 'james' || name === 'john') console.log('Your name is james *or* john');
```

---

If you have a lengthy amount of aliases you want to use, you can put them in an array and use the [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method, which will return `true` if one of the array elements is equal to the given argument.

```js
const aliases = ['slowmode', 'sm', 'slow', 'sl', 'unfast'];

if (aliases.includes(command))
```

```js
const names = ['john', 'james', 'jonah', 'jack', 'jerry']
const winner = 'jack'

if (names.includes(winner)) console.log('One of these people is the winner')
```

---

> I also want the bot to embed the response, instead of just sending it like a normal one.

Visit [this page](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds) from the official `discord.js` guide to learn all about embeds; including how to make and customize them. To make a basic embed, you can either use the constructor or the object:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

// regular text
message.channel.send("You did not specify a correct amount of time!");

// *sample* embed constructor
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
  .setColor("RED")
  .setTitle("You did not specify a correct amount of time!")
  .setFooter("Please try again");

message.channel.send(embed);

// *sample* embed object
const embed = {
  color: "RED",
  title: "You did not specify a correct amount of time!",
  footer: "Please try again",
};

message.channel.send({ embed });
```

- [All `MessageEmbed()` constructor methods and object properties](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed)

Comment: I also recommend https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/ wich will learn you how to make an alias system and other cool stuff for your Command Handling.